# How to enable Content-MD5 tag in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, apache2, apache2.4, mod-deflate

I just installed a sole `Apache 2.4` (without any other modules like `Php` or what else) and intended to host static files on it. The static files are placed under `/var/www/html/test-files/`. I tried to enable the `core` `ContentDigest` (documented by Apache2 at [Apache2 Core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#page-header)) by two ways:

1. Create `.htaccess` under `/var/www/html/test-files/` and added `ContentDigest On` to the file.
2. Edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and added following to it:
   `<Directory /var/www/html/test-files/>`
       `ContentDigest On`
   `</Directory>`

I used Inspect feature of Google Chrome to test downloading some `.html` and `mp4` files but couldn't see any `Content-MD5` tag included in headers.

Note: all configs are default.

Do I mis-understand something here? How can I enable the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did solving the issue by using the second approach **PLUS** disabling `mod_deflate`:

```
sudo a2dismod deflate
sudo service apache2 restart
```